# How to solve this second order ODE: $y\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\big(\frac{dy}{dx}\big)^2=y\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having some trouble with this ODE. I got to the point $v=\frac{y}{2}+\frac{C}{y}$ after substituting $v=\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $v'=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=v\frac{dv}{dy}$, but I'm not sure where to go from here. My initial thought was to integrate $v$ to find $y$, but the equation is entirely in terms of $y$ instead of $x$. I don't think I can integrate $v$ with respect to $x$ when the equation isn't solved for $y$. I put the problem involving v and y, $\frac{dv}{dy}+\frac{v}{y}=1$, into Wolframalpha and found that $v=\frac{y}{2}+\frac{C}{y}$ is correct. I just need to solve for y in terms of x now.

Comment: LHS is derivative of RHS.

Comment: $(y'y)'=y'y$ this is separable  then you can  integrate

Comment: Or $(y^2)''=(y^2)'$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** As eyeballfrog mentioned in their comment, we can rewrite the left-hand side is
$$yy'' + (y')^2 = (yy')',$$
so the equation is $$(yy')' = yy',$$
hence $$yy' = \frac{C}{2} \exp x$$
for some constant $C$ (where we include the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ for later convenience).
But this equation is separable (for all constants $C$).

> Integrating yields $$y^2 = C \exp x + D.$$

Comment: So I understand how you got $(yy')'=yy'$, but I'm not sure how you got to $yy'=\frac{C}{2}\exp x$.

Comment: @Devon In terms of $u := yy'$, the equation is $u' = u$, and the solutions $u$ to that equation, i.e., the functions that are their own derivatives, are the constant multiples of $\exp x$.

Answer (score 1):

> $$y\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=y\frac{dy}{dx}$$
> after substituting $v=dy/dx$ and $v′=\dfrac {d^2y}{dx^2}=v\dfrac {dv}{dy}$, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

$$vy\frac{dv}{dy}+v^2=yv$$
$$v\left(y\frac{dv}{dy}+v-y\right)=0$$
$v=0 \implies y=C$ so $y$ is constant anf you also have:
$$y\frac{dv}{dy}+v-y=0$$
$$(yv)'=y$$
integrate.  You can also substitute in the original DE $v=y'y$ then the DE is just separable:
$$v'=v$$